# Mock urlopen in unknown subpackage

Tags: python, mocking, urllib

I want to mock out calls to `urllib.request.urlopen` in a module. It works when it's a single file, but when I put it in a package and import the module in the package's `__init__.py`, I cannot mock it out anymore.

## Reproduction

Imagine I have two modules in a `test` package:

- `module.py`

  ```
  from urllib.request import urlopen

  def do_it():
      print(urlopen.__module__)
      urlopen('test')
  ```
- `module_test.py`

  ```
  from unittest import mock
  from .module import do_it


  def test_not_working():
      with mock.patch('urllib.request.urlopen', lambda url: print(url)):
          do_it()


  def test_plain():
      with mock.patch('test.module.urlopen', lambda url: print(url)):
          do_it()
  ```

`test_not_working` prints `urllib.request` as the module for `urlopen`, since I patched the local `urlopen` function in the test module, and the test fails because `test` is not a valid URL.
`test_plain` prints `.module`, because I succesfully patched `urlopen`, and the test succeeds and prints `test`.

My issue is that I have moved `.module` into a package, because I wanted to group multiple files I created. It now looks like this:

- `module`

  - `__init__.py`

    ```
    from .module import do_it
    ```
  - `module.py` (same as `module.py` before)
- `test_module.py`

  ```
  from unittest import mock
  from .module import do_it


  def test_packaged_fails():
      with mock.patch('test.module.urlopen', lambda url: print(url)):
          do_it()

  def test_packaged_works():
      with mock.patch('test.module.module.urlopen', lambda url: print(url)):
          do_it()
  ```

The first two tests stay the same, but `test_packaged` prints `urllib.request`, and fails as the first test because the URL `test` is invalid.

I understand that I failed to mock `urlopen`, because it evidently doesn't use `test.module.urlopen` but `test.module.module.urlopen`.

## Restrictions

### Actual Project

I don't know how to fix this issue, because of the module is just one of many on an open source project ([OpenMensa Parsers](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/openmensa-parsers/tree/alternate-website)). The [Aachener parser](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/openmensa-parsers/tree/alternate-website/parsers/aachen) is a package containing multiple files, instead of a single file module like the other parsers.
The issue mentioned above occurs when I want to [upgrade snapshots](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/openmensa-parsers/blob/alternate-website/parsers/tests/update_snapshots.py) for our regression tests. It is supposed to cache all requests that a parser makes, so that the test can be reproduced later, even if the website changes.

### List

I have the following restrictions:

- I cannot hard code the path to the submodule (`test.module.module.urlopen`), because I want to use the snapshot generation for the other parsers as well.
- I can only use libraries that are available as Debian Wheezy packages, because of the build system and deployment. [See the currently installed dependencies.](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/openmensa-parsers/blob/alternate-website/build_scripts/travis-install-deps.sh#L4)
- I would like to stay with `urllib.request.urlopen` for consistency with the other parsers.
- I actually do not call `do_it()` directly. I call a function from another module that dynamically imports `do_it()` from different parser modules and then calls it. I will leave the minimal example above as is for simplicity.

## Question

How can I patch `urlopen` in the package, if I do not know the subpackage it is called in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to modify the import statement in `module/module.py`:

```
from urllib import request

def do_it():
    print(urlopen.__module__)
    request.urlopen('test')
```

This makes it possible to mock it using:

```
with mock.patch('urllib.request.urlopen', lambda url: print(url)):
    do_it()
```

However this is a workaround that requires changing the module under test. I am still interested in a way find the submodule that imported `urlopen` directly and mock it out there.

Comment: well this is called writing code for test-ability I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what function uses `urlopen`, and you know it accesses `urlopen` through a module-level `from urllib.request import urlopen`, then you can perform the patch through the function's global variable dict:

```
with mock.patch.dict(do_it.__globals__, urlopen=whatever):
    do_whatever_with(do_it)
```

Ultimately, mocking in Python will still require a lot of implementation detail knowledge about the tested code's imports.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me, because the package `module/` does not have an attribute `__globals__`. I would have to add it myself, and I'm not sure how to do that.
While this would be definitely cleaner, the root problem is that I want to know how to programmatically find the function inside some package's module, and save myself from adapting that module or the package.

Comment: @J0hj0h: The package doesn't have a `__globals__` attribute. The *function* has a `__globals__` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! In the actual code I do not have direct access to that function, since I call it indirectly. I have updated the restrictions to point to this. Nevertheless, your answer is interesting. I learned something! :)